# Rank a sorted dataset using apply function

Tags: r, sorting, ranking, tapply

My dataframe looks like this:

```
head(temp$HName)

[1] "UNIVERSITY OF TEXAS HEALTH SCIENCE CENTER AT TYLER"
[2] "METHODIST HOSPITAL,THE"                            
[3] "TOMBALL REGIONAL MEDICAL CENTER"                   
[4] "METHODIST SUGAR LAND HOSPITAL"                     
[5] "GULF COAST MEDICAL CENTER"                         
[6] "VHS HARLINGEN HOSPITAL COMPANY LLC"   

head(temp$Rate)

[1] 7.3 8.3 8.7 8.7 8.8 8.9
76 Levels: 7.3 8.3 8.7 8.8 8.9 9 9.1 9.2 9.3 9.4 9.5 9.6 ... 17.1

> head(temp$Rank)
[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

The `temp$Rate` is sorted. I am trying to write a function `assignRank` which gives me a new column `temp$Rank` which has values as 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5

My code is as below:

```
tapply(temp$Rank,temp$Rate, assignRank)
```

where :

```
    assignRank<- function(r=1){
      temp$Rank <- r
      r <- r + 1
      return(r)
    }
```

I get following error when running `tapply`

```
   tapply(temp$Rank,temp$Rate, assignRank)
 Show Traceback

 Rerun with Debug
 Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "Rank", value = c(NA, NA)) : 
  replacement has 2 rows, data has 301
```

Please advise where I am going wrong?

Comment: Why don't you use R's `rank` function?

Comment: hi Roland!. rank function has three ways to tackle ties which is first, random and average. In case i use "first" or "random" the rank as i understand from documentation will give the rank of 3rd and 4th row of my data set as 3,4. If I use average it will average out this two values. I want to preserve the rank of tied element which in my example is 3,3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use `data.table` for stuff like this, because both sorting and ranking are very efficient/simple syntax

```
library(data.table)
setkey(setDT(temp), Rate) # This will sort your data set by Rate in case it's not yet sorted
temp[, Rank := .GRP, by = Rate]
temp
#                                                 HName Rate Rank
# 1: UNIVERSITY OF TEXAS HEALTH SCIENCE CENTER AT TYLER  7.3    1
# 2:                             METHODIST HOSPITAL,THE  8.3    2
# 3:                    TOMBALL REGIONAL MEDICAL CENTER  8.7    3
# 4:                      METHODIST SUGAR LAND HOSPITAL  8.7    3
# 5:                          GULF COAST MEDICAL CENTER  8.8    4
# 6:                 VHS HARLINGEN HOSPITAL COMPANY LLC  8.9    5
```

Or you could easily do the same using base R (assuming your data is sorted by Rank) just do

```
as.numeric(factor(temp$Rate))
## [1] 1 2 3 3 4 5
```

Or could also use `dense_rank` function from `dplyr` package (which will *not* require sorting the data set)

```
library(dplyr)
temp %>% 
  mutate(Rank = dense_rank(Rate))
#                                                HName Rate Rank
# 1 UNIVERSITY OF TEXAS HEALTH SCIENCE CENTER AT TYLER  7.3    1
# 2                             METHODIST HOSPITAL,THE  8.3    2
# 3                    TOMBALL REGIONAL MEDICAL CENTER  8.7    3
# 4                      METHODIST SUGAR LAND HOSPITAL  8.7    3
# 5                          GULF COAST MEDICAL CENTER  8.8    4
# 6                 VHS HARLINGEN HOSPITAL COMPANY LLC  8.9    5
```

Answer (score 0):

Other options (if the data is ordered)

```
with(temp, cumsum(ave(Rate, Rate, FUN=function(x) c(1,x[-1]!=x[-length(x)]))))
#[1] 1 2 3 3 4 5



 with(temp, match(Rate, unique(Rate)) )
#[1] 1 2 3 3 4 5
```